# PHP namespace return to the global namespace after initiating

Tags: php, namespaces

Good day,

I am trying to master PHP namespaces.
In my application I created a class called "panelselector"
Now I have put this in the namespace "htmlsnippets"

```
namespace htmlsnippets;

class panelselector {

}
```

When running it goes just fine:

```
new \htmlsnippets\panelselector;
```

However when trying to execute something inside that class that's inside the global namespace it stops working.
Something inside me tells me something like. dohooo. logic! But I do not know how to revert to the global namespace right after initiating the *panelselector* class

```
namespace htmlsnippets;

class panelselector {
    public $panels = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->panels = DBA::ROWS('karolina_panels', 'WHERE `panel_id` = ?', array(24));
    }
}
```

This returns me :

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'htmlsnippets\DBA' not found on karolina\system\app\classes\htmlsnippets\panelselector.class.php in line 177
```

*Answer by : **"Grumpy says Reinstate Monica"***

> is DBA:: in your root namespace? If so, append a backslash when
>   calling it. \DBA::ROWS(...) – Grumpy says Reinstate Monica 5 hours ago

Works!! :-)

Comment: You also need to define path for DBA

Comment: is `DBA::` in your root namespace? If so, append a backslash when calling it. `\DBA::ROWS(...)`

Comment: Grumpy says Reinstate Monica -- THNX! If you add it as an answer I can accept it :-)